# Problems with JAXB, Marshal, - unable to marshal type “java.lang.String”

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

when I run the marshal operation I get the following error:

```
javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "java.lang.String" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation]
    ...

Caused by: com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "java.lang.String" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.reportError(XMLSerializer.java:237)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.LeafBeanInfoImpl.serializeRoot(LeafBeanInfoImpl.java:126)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.XMLSerializer.childAsRoot(XMLSerializer.java:483)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.MarshallerImpl.write(MarshallerImpl.java:308)
    ... 6 more
```

This is my function for Marshalling...

```
public StringBuffer Marshaller(Object marshall){   // make marshalling->Java to XML
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        try {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext=JAXBContext.newInstance(marshall.getClass());
            Marshaller jaxbMarshaller=jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            // çıktı
            jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            jaxbMarshaller.marshal(marshall, writer);
            System.out.println(writer.getBuffer().toString());
        } catch (PropertyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return writer.getBuffer();

    }
```

Thanks for your interests..

Answer (score 13):

You can't marshal just a `String` as it doesn't have any root element information (hence the exception about the missing `@XmlRootElement` annotation), but you can wrap it in an instance of `JAXBElement` and then marshal that.  `JAXBElement` is another way to supply this root element information to JAXB.

**Example of Creating the `JAXBElement`**

```
JAXBElement<String> jaxbElement =
  new JAXBElement(new QName("root-element"), 
    String.class, string);
```

**If you Generated your Model From an XML Schema**

If you created your object model from an XML Schema.  And you have a top-level XML element that is a data type like `xs:string` then there will be a convenience method on the generated `ObjectFactory` class that will help you create the `JAXBElement` instance.

Comment: Could you please explain more  ?

Comment: @nurdankaraman - I have added some additional information to my answer.