# Spring Hateoas, PathVariable and SaxSerialization

Tags: java, spring

I m actually developping a little application to train, and I m facing a problem using Spring Hateoas using PathVariable.

In fact, when I use something like :

```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/directories/{idDirectory}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public DirectoryDTO findById(@PathVariable String idDirectory) {
        DirectoryEntity directoryEntity = directoryService.findById(idDirectory);
        DirectoryDTO directoryDto = new DirectoryDTO(directoryEntity);
        directoryDto.add(linkTo(methodOn(DirectoryController.class).findById(idDirectory)).withSelfRel());
        return directoryDto;
    }
```

I've got an error like the following one :

> [com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2]: unable to marshal type DirectoryDTO
>   to element because it's missing an annotation

Here my DirectoryEntity :

```
@Document(collection = "directory")
public class DirectoryEntity {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private String path;
    private List<DirectoryEntity> childrenDirectories;
    private DirectoryEntity parentDirectory;
    private List<FileEntity> fileEntities;

/* Get/set omitted */
}
```

And the DTO :

```
public class DirectoryDTO extends Resource<DirectoryEntity> {


    public DirectoryDTO(DirectoryEntity content, Link... links) {
        super(content, links);
    }

    public DirectoryDTO(DirectoryEntity content, Iterable<Link> links) {
        super(content, links);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Is the a `RestController`?  Otherwise, you probably need to add `@ResponseBody` to your method declaration.

Comment: it's a RestController, sorry I didn't tell it

Comment: Try to add @XmlRootElement annotation to your DirectoryDTO class.

Comment: Not working. I got : "no default constructor", but Hateoas Resource needs constructors with parameters

Comment: yes it will get your constructors but try add the default one , cause its being used in order to wrap the object and then populate it with the setters / getters methods

Comment: The default one in rejected due to the implementation of Resource<DirectoryEntity>

Comment: follow these links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26166751/problems-with-jaxb-marshal-unable-to-marshal-type-java-lang-string  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23480517/spring-hateoas-w-spring-boot-jaxb-marshal-error-when-returning-a-resourcest

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the `@XmlRootElement(name = "directoryEntity")` 's annotation in DirectoryDTO.

Comment: I tried this and I got : "This page contains the following errors:

error on line 2 at column 93: Entity 'eacute' not defined
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error."

Comment: Your original probolem has changed. Maybe, you have an error in your frontend, It's expects the "eacute" entity

Comment: I dont have a front end, I m using RestController without any page rendering. Only direct output from the controller

Comment: You have to replace &*acute for numertical entity representation in you model. See this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4656121/oacute-not-allowed-in-xml-file-but-allowed-in-net-resource-file

Comment: The problem is that I think Spring (with its dependencies) is not able (using hateoas module) to parse the { char in  @RequestMapping(value = "/directories/{idDirectory}